# Pyroot AttributeError while importing histograms

Tags: python, linux, root-framework, pyroot

I have a problem with pyroot. When I try to import a ROOT histogram I get the same AttributeError all the time.

```
>>> from ROOT import TH1F
AttributeError: type object 'TArray' has no attribute '__getitem__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemError: <built-in method mro of ROOT.PyRootType object at 0x328fb18> returned a result with an error set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'TH1F'
```

I also tried rootpy which doesn't work. Probably related?

I have Python 3.5 installed and did a clean install of ROOT with gcc 5.2.0. The Python module is listed when I run `root-config --features`.

Any ideas? Or solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is related to a recent change in Python which solved wrong exception handling. A call in the `Pythonize.cxx` wrapper tries to rename the `__getitem__` attribute to the class `TArray` which doesn't exist. This leads to an AttributeError which was ignored in Python until the new python3.5 release.

To restore the old behaviour, you need to modify the file `Utility.cxx` in your `$ROOTSYS/bindings/pyroot/src/` directory. Search for the method

```
Bool_t PyROOT::Utility::AddToClass( PyObject* pyclass, const char* label, const char* func )
```

which should be at around line 230. In this method is a if condition:

```
if ( ! pyfunc )
    return kFALSE;
```

Here you need to replace the code above with the following lines:

```
if ( ! pyfunc ) {
   PyErr_Clear();
   return kFALSE;
}
```

The call of `PyErr_Clear()` will fix this. Save the file and recompile your ROOT installation. This should fix the problem.

Edit: There's already a bug report for this issue: https://sft.its.cern.ch/jira/browse/ROOT-7640